# enable php in Weebly using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using Weebly to build my website. I need to insert php script and was told by the host to modify the .htaccess file. I found the following code:

RemoveHandler `.html .htm`

AddType `application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm`

The weird thing is that the first time I added this to the htaccess file, it looked like php parsing was enabled. After 2 weeks I accessed my site again and php was no longer enabled, and these 2 lines that I added were missing. I added back these 2 lines, trying various positions in the htaccess file, but I could no longer enable php. I asked the host rep and she was not much help. The entire htaccess file is listed below. Is there anything in it that prevents php parsing?

```
#Weebly Additions Start
DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml index.xhtml index.wml index.perl index.pl index.plx index.ppl index.cgi index.jsp index.js index.jp index.php4 index.php3 index.php index.phtml index.htm home.htm default.htm index.fcgi
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php

Options -Indexes
# Send send no-cache headers for root (/) and (.html) files
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(^/|\.html)$" HTML_FILE
Header add Pragma "no-cache" env=HTML_FILE
Header add Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0,  must-revalidate" env=HTML_FILE
Header add Expires "-1" env=HTML_FILE


RewriteEngine On


# stop condition
RewriteRule ^mobile/.*$ - [L]

#Redirect urls based on a query string parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?view=mobile([^&]*)&?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?m%1%3 [CO=is_mobile:1:%    {HTTP_HOST},CO=disable_mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST},L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m*(.*&)?view=full([^&]*)&?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%3 [CO=disable_mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST},L,R]

# only process HTML files
# ----------------------------------------------------
RemoveHandler .htm .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm 

RewriteRule (^|\.html)$ - [S=1]
    # is an html file, start the tests...

RewriteRule .* - [S=9]
    # NOT html file, skip past mobile rules...


# tests
# ----------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mobile$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?m [CO=is_mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST},CO=disable_mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST},L,R]
    # set cookies, redirect...

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^full$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [CO=disable_mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST},L,R]
    # set cookies, redirect...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|;)\s*is_mobile=0
RewriteRule .* - [S=6]
    # skip past mobile rules...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|;)\s*disable_mobile=1
RewriteRule .* - [S=5]
    # skip past mobile rules...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|;)\s*is_mobile=1
RewriteRule .* - [S=2]
    # go to mobile rules...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [CO=is_mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST},S=1]
    # go to mobile rules...

RewriteRule .* - [CO=is_mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST},S=2]
    # set cookie, skip past mobile rules...


# mobile rules
# ----------------------------------------------------

RewriteRule ^$ /mobile/index.html [S=1,PT]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/$1 [PT]
#Weebly Additions End
```